# When refresh browser then error come "can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Error image:

[image]

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
    usersession = req.session;    
    if (usersession.loggedin == true)
        res.redirect('/home');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));   
});
```

When home page refresh then error comes

Comment: error come on CMD please see the image.

Comment: the `redirect` function closes the `response`. you can't use the same `response` after you already sent it, so if `(usersession.loggedin == true)`, you respond with `redirect` and then `sendFile` so you get the error

Comment: Thank You... Tom, Issue solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` doesnt stop `res.sendFile` from executing after you have redirected.

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
    usersession = req.session;    

    if (usersession.loggedin) {
        return res.redirect('/home');
    }

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));   
});
```

Note: You should be ideally using [router](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) instead of `app`.

Comment: But page does not load

Comment: app.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
    usersession = req.session;    

    if (usersession.loggedin) 
        return res.redirect('/home');
    else
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));   
});  This can be use here